# Google Cloud MySQL and Master-master replication

Tags: mysql, replication, google-cloud-sql, multi-master-replication

I have two servers in different regions (`eu`, `us`) connected to the same mysql database, I've started with google cloud sql second generation but it's only available on `us` region.

The idea is to add a second sql nodes in the new region `eu` but I can't find any documentation about Master-Master replication so it is not supported at this time. Is this correct?

ps. both of my servers need read/write access.

With my operational google sql in `us`, can I just:

1. I create a new google sql cloud in `eu`.
2. Configure `eu` as an External Replicas for `us`.
3. Configure `eu` as External Masters for `us`.

I'm really confused! Any help will be appreciated.

/Ouss

Comment: Google has SQL-ish replicated database called cloud-spanner

Comment: I think I’ll do it using spanner, it’s not really cheap but let’s see and I will update this question with my feedback, thanks midor

Comment: There's always the possibility to use a container or vm as a service, if you know how to do the setup

Comment: I would be interested in how it went for you. Will you add feedback at some point?

Comment: I've installed mysql server in a VM, then the master master replication as normal, no big deal.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Ofc. that works; kind of defeats the purpose of using Cloud SQL in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Master-Master is not supported in Google Cloud SQL.

Comment: Yes I’ve noticed that but I’m asking about a workaround or an idea, have someone did it in a cloud ? Should I install my own mysql server a tke care of all and do it myself...

Comment: I highly doubt there is a workaround. Even if there is, it would not be supported so may break any time.

I recommend you to step back and think about what you are really trying to archieve. master-master in traditional SQL databases is not a magic bullet and have a lot of problems. If you really need multi-region consistent database, look at Spanner.

Comment: FYI for those considering, AWS has had multi-master for quite a long time now...

Answer (score 0):

Solution from:
https://www.ryadel.com/en/mysql-master-master-replication-setup-in-5-easy-steps/

Successfully implemented on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 in google cloud platform
MySql 5.7 will not load on Debian.

/// Install MySQL on 2 VMs

A. On VMs sql1 & sql2

```
apt update
apt install mysql-server -y

P@ssW0rd2020    P@ssW0rd2020
```

B. Comment bind-address to allow global access

```
cd /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

C. Restart MySQL Service (cnf changed)

```
systemctl restart mysql
systemctl status mysql
```

D. On sql1

```
nano /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf

[mysqld]   // note: not [mysql]

server-id=1
log-bin="mysql-bin"
binlog-ignore-db=test
binlog-ignore-db=information_schema
replicate-ignore-db=test
replicate-ignore-db=information_schema
relay-log="mysql-relay-log"
auto-increment-increment = 2
auto-increment-offset = 1

-------------------------------------

systemctl restart mysql
systemctl status mysql
```

D. On sql2

```
nano /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf

[mysqld]

server-id=2
log-bin="mysql-bin"
binlog-ignore-db=test
binlog-ignore-db=information_schema
replicate-ignore-db=test
replicate-ignore-db=information_schema
relay-log="mysql-relay-log"
auto-increment-increment = 2
auto-increment-offset = 2

-------------------------------------

systemctl restart mysql (THIS WILL CREATE BIN LOG)
systemctl status mysql

again, flush privileges; ---supposed to
```

E. Create the Replicator User(s)

- Configure on both sql1 & 2 (replicator password can be same for, or not)

  mysql -u root -p

  P@ssW0rd2020

  CREATE USER 'replicator'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'P@ssW0rd2020';
  GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'replicator'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'P@ssW0rd2020';
  flush privileges;

F. Start with fresh VMs with no databases (better) or mutual import/export databases into sql1 & 2
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/copying-databases.html

G. Configure replication from sql1 to sql2
(make sql2 slave of sql1)

- On sql1

  SHOW MASTER STATUS;

  example output:
  +------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
  | File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
  +------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
  | mysql-bin.000001 |      448 | example      | test, informatio |
  +------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
  1 row in set (0.00 sec)

  - NOTE 'file' and 'position' values
- On sql2

  STOP SLAVE;
  CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST = '104.154.225.215', MASTER_USER = 'replicator', MASTER_PASSWORD = 'P@ssW0rd2020', MASTER_LOG_FILE = 'mysql-bin.000001', MASTER_LOG_POS = 448;
  START SLAVE;
  flush privileges;

H. Repeat for sql2 (make sql1 slave of sql2)

- on sql2

  SHOW MASTER STATUS;

  example output:
  +------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
  | File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
  +------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
  | mysql-bin.000001 |      448 | example      | test, informatio |
  +------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
  1 row in set (0.00 sec)

  - NOTE 'file' and 'position' values
- On sql1

  STOP SLAVE;
  CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST = '35.198.195.130', MASTER_USER = 'replicator', MASTER_PASSWORD = 'P@ssW0rd2020', MASTER_LOG_FILE = 'mysql-bin.000001', MASTER_LOG_POS = 448;
  START SLAVE;

I. Test the Replication

- Create a database on sql1 it will be replicated on sql2, vice versa.
- Create a database on sql2 it will be replicated on sql1, vice versa.

SUCCESS IS SWEET!