# Is there a way to create a non-read-only Cloud SQL MySQL replica in GCP?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

We want to create a Cloud SQL replica of an external MySQL database. I have tried the steps in [Replicating from an external server](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/replication-from-external), but I ended up with a read-only replica.

I tried creating a new MySQL instance, then when I tried loading the dump produced by `mysqldump --master-data=1`, I got the following error:

```
Import failed: Import error: exit status 1 ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 18: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

Line 18 is:

`SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN= 0;`

According to [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/system-variable-privileges.html)
    you need `SUPER` privilege to set `sql_log_bin`.

I need to create a second schema on the replica that needs to be writable. Is there a way to set up replication into a non-read-only Cloud SQL MySQL instance where I can create another schema?

Comment: A master to master configuration is not possible in Cloud SQL. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47204223/google-cloud-mysql-and-master-master-replication) or [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/google-cloud-sql-discuss/BrivbTEi_NI/Vb1oJyMVAAAJ). The only other type of replicas Cloud SQL has are [failover replicas](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability), but I don't think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: When replicating an external MySQL database to Cloud SQL, you have a read only replica. You can break the replica and promote to a master. If you want read-write then you will need to set up your own MySQL server on a VM. Cloud SQL does not support what you want to do. Note: it is possible to manually enable write for a replica. Make sure you understand the implications and know how to exclude tables from replication (on your own MySQL instance and not Cloud SQL).

Comment: @JohnHanley, thanks. I am going the route of setting up MySQL on a VM. You should make this comment an answer and I will accept it.